# How to override the width of a TextField component with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming, material-ui

I'm trying to reduce the width of the [`TextField`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/) component :

Here is the render method:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <TextField
                  hintText="Email"
                  ref="email"
                /><br/>
                <TextField
                  hintText="Password"
                  type="password"
                  ref="password"
                /><br/>
              <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.loginCommand}><i className="fa fa-sign-in"/>{' '}Log In</button>
            </form>
          </div>
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've looked at the parameters, inputStyle etc...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You also can look at [`fullWidth` property](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/649ef2e34c10c90788b7506e88958c91f87f924c/src/TextField/TextField.js#L171) to make sure it is set properly.

```
<TextField
      id="full-width-text-field"
      label="Label"
      placeholder="Placeholder"
      helperText="Full width!"
      margin="normal"
      fullWidth // this may override your custom width
/>
```

Comment: This does not "reduce" the width of the component as OP had asked. This actually will increase the width in certain cases.

Comment: make sure to surround 'true' with curly braces - fullWidth={true}

Answer (score 47):

You could either specify inline style on element like below

```
  <TextField
        hintText="Email"
        ref="email"
        style = {{width: 100}} //assign the width as your requirement
   />
```

Or you could do as below.

Declare a `styles` variable with css properties.

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textFld: { width: 100, height: 40}   //assign the width as your requirement
});
```

Assign it to `style` in your `render` code.

```
<TextField
              hintText="Email"
              ref="email"
              style = {styles.textFld}
            />
```

Give it try let me know if it works for you. I am new to react js as well.

You could refer to documentations and other similar question on SO for clarity.
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html#content

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#content

[React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)

Comment: is it working? My text field is working correct if width is 250 px but for smaller width it is not working

Answer (score 11):

If you want to make the [`TextField`](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)'s width expanded as much as the parent's width (`width: 100%`):

```js
<TextField label="Full width" fullWidth />
```

If you want to set the `TextField`'s width to the exact value:

```js
<Box width={350}>
  <TextField label="width: 350px" fullWidth />
</Box>
```

You can also set the style of the `TextField` directly if you don't want to add a wrapper component:

**V5**

```js
<TextField label="width: 350px" sx={{ width: 350 }} />
```

**V4**

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 350
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField label="width: 350px" className={classes.root} />;
}
```

I'd advice you against using inline styles as suggested in other answers since inline styles are harder to override. You should by default use [Material-UI styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#material-ui-styles) because it's more flexible and better integrated with Material-UI components. For example, you can [cherry-pick](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#makestyles) the sub-components to override in a larger components, or style psuedo classes and elements, which can't be done with inline style.

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 35093107/how-to-override-the-width-of-a-textfield-component-with-react-material-ui]

Comment: The `sx` part of the answer *should* work; it doesn't :(