# Why doesn't react let me use plain old html in jsx?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I just started a project in React. Somewhere I have read or seen a video that the creators were proud that unlike Angular you don't need to learn new tags and you use just plain old html.

I was quite surprised that react make me change `<img style="..." />` to `<img styles="" />. (It's`style`vs`styles`.)

My question is have I set something wrong or is it correct behaviour of JSX templates? How can I use plain old html in JSX?

The error I received was

> invariant.js:38Uncaught Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Comment: Because jsx !====================== html (the operator here means "veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery not equal") "How can I use plain old html in JSX?" --- you cannot. It just occasionally looks similar, but they don't share any roots.

Comment: Zerkms, I see. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want to keep you in-line style, you should have `style={<your-css-rules>}`, instead of `styles="<your-css-rules>"`.

However, as tempting as it might seem to use in-line styling in React, I would keep the lesson learned about separation of concerns and use css classes.

So, in your example, you could do something like

```
// CSS

imgClass {
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
}

// HTML
<img className="imgClass" />
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31638988/2794702) gives a good overview on when to avoid using in-line styling in React.

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

for inline style ,`style` is the correct way