# Where should styles be in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I want to know where should **CSS, SASS** like styles be in **react**?

It is good to style within each component? Provide an example styling example within the component if possible....

Where should be layout specific classes like *bootstrap* `col-md-4` be?  Isn't it easy to have layout structure in one location rather than within the component?

PS: Is inline styling preferred? or what are alternatives for that... 
   And possible way to organize layout in one center location rather than setting layout in multiple components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js inline style best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

This previous Stack Overflow question might be a helpful read for you:

[React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)