# using inline css in spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying use inline css in html content but it shows the error you see in the picture below;

[image]

How can I use inline css in spfx webpart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to do it is as follows,
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div className={`ms-Grid-col ms-u-md3`} style={{"border-color": "black"}}>
//Some Code
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for post:)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to do it. You should better use the sass files and define your styles there. Since this is not HTML, but JSX you can do something like this:

```
var style = {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 200
    };

return <div style={style}> Have a good and productive day! </div>;
```

but this is not recommended. The code piece is not mine, but taken from this post [React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)