# how to style for top-right-bottom-left for jsx css and selector like first-of-type?

Tags: css, jsx

this code would work in normal css:

```
padding: 10 5 15 20
```

but in jsx inline style for react it won't also, I cannot:

```
styles.p: first-of-type { 
    color: red
}
```

I don't want to make a css file, so I want to style from each component. help?

Comment: *"This code would work in normal css: `padding: 10 5 15 20`"* - I beg to differ! Consider reading [this question and the associated answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices) for more information.

Comment: I meant in a css file, but in jsx it won't, it'd work if I do paddingLeft, paddingRight.... but it's too much typo for other styles, I don't want to override it in another css file but I am having hard time I cannot figure out, also for my buttons, I can't make selectors like first-of-type work :/

Comment: Doesn't matter what you're using, I was pointing out that your syntax won't work without a unit - `padding: 10 5 15 20` won't work without `px`. Anyway, in the link I included, it shows some alternatives.

Comment: I tried px, but it's error, thank you for the links