# How to read react syntax

Tags: reactjs

In the following:

```
<div style={{marginTop:'10%'}}>
```

do I read this as style is an object (the outer {}) that contains an array (the inner {}) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)

Answer (score 3):

In JSX, everything gets wrapped in curly braces `{}`. When you see a set of `{}`, then you know that what's inside of them is JavaScript. For the style prop, it accepts an object. So your style is `{marginTop: '10%'}` and it's wrapped in JSX `{}`. You could also write it as this:

```
const customStyle = { marginTop: '10%' };

<div style={customStyle}></div>
```

The `{}` just let React know that you are using JavaScript instead of a string.

Answer (score 2):

The outer `{}` indicate that the value of the attribute is an expression to be evaluated, rather than a static string. (You never use static strings with the `style` attribute in React; you can with other attributes.) The content of the expression is any valid JavaScript expression; in this case, an object initializer defining an object with a property called `marginTop` with a value `'10%'`. (This is how you set the `style` of an element in React: Via an object.) There are no arrays in the example.

I suggest working through the [Intro to React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) to get the lay of the land.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different languages intermixed here.

The outer language is JSX. It's the part that resembles HTML, but compiles to Javascript. The outer {} is part of the JSX syntax, meaning "what's inside is Javascript".

The inside of the expression constructs a Javascript object. That syntax also uses the brace, enclosing a set of key-value pairs. That object is interpreted as a style.

Within the outer braces, you can use any Javascript expression. So you could write your method as:

```
render() { 
    const style = {marginTop:'10%'};
    return <div style={style}>;
}
```

This is a Javascript method, which returns an object created in JSX, containing a reference to the `style` value created in Javascript.

Technically it's all one language, JSX being a superset of Javascript, but I think it's helpful to describe the extensions as JSX and the regular part as just Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is read as an object (inner `{}`) containing one property `marginTop` passed as a property do a div element via outer `{}`.