# Syntax error: Identifier directly after number when using inline style in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got some error when using inline style in react js and I don't know what's mean 
[image]

I think using brackets in inline style, for instance, would work,

Comment: remove the semicolon before `Transition`, make all values strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)

Answer (score 4):

The React style prop requires a valid javascript object with camelCased property names. The values in the key value pair can be a number or a string (or a variable representing one of those 2 items). See [React Docs for more information](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

A style object would look like:

```
const style = { 
      transform: "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)", 
      transition: "0s"
    }
```

Notice that there are no semi-colons, the values are strings and each css property/value is separated by commas.

> Note: you can pass numbers for pixel based values and React will add the "px" for you. However in the case above for the 0px it won't work as it is part of a string and not just a simple number.

try:

```
style={{ transform: "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)", transition: "0s"}}
```

or, using the var I created above:

```
style={style}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ,