# how to add dynamic css in react js

Tags: reactjs

can we achieve this in React js style={style} ??

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     style_title: {"color": "blue"}
   };
 this.change = this.change.bind(this);
}

change(e) { 
 this.setState({ 
   [e.target.name]: e.target.value }) 
}
```

**My Form**:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value={this.props.title} onChange={e =>this.changeEdit(e)} /> 
<input type="text" name="style_title" value={this.props.style_title} onChange={e =>this.changeEdit(e)} />
```

title text print on preview mode for this I need to styles title dynamically using input field for ex:

```
{ "color": "blue", "font-size": "22px",}
```

above styles should apply render `<p style={style}>{this.props.title }</p>` in style attribute

**Preview Section**:

```
render = () => (
 const style = this.props.style_title; 

 return (
     <p style={style}>{this.props.title }</p>
 );
)
```

[image: My form look this with preview mode]

Comment: Possible duplication of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices

Comment: your question need to explain more that you wrote, your desire is a little unclear, Do you mean, you wanna have a form to get the style and implement it to another component?

Comment: yes , once I click submit value should updated
this.state {title:"",custom_css:""}

Answer (score 4):

In `React` you can pass dynamic style either by passing object as mentioned here:
[React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)

Or you can also pass inline like:

```
<div style={{ height: '10%' }}>
  Hello World!
</div>
```

One note though, the css properties will be in `camelCase`, e.g. `borderBottom: '10px'`

Comment: I need to add custom css as user input form fields to style text

Comment: In that case, you will need to save the form input value to your component `state` as an object. And then in your `render()` method you need to or should be using the `state` values in desired area/place like `this.state.myStyleProp1`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but only if `style_title` holds the object and **not** just string value. e.g. `this.state = {style_title: {height: '20px', width: '90px'}}` 
So then you can use it the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

One of the way to change styles in react, is by using ternary operators.

```js
<div className={3>2 ? "red" : "black"} >
 // write your code here
</div>
```