# Use state variable as Style props value

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a state variable that holds the name of the theme (Light, Dark, etc).

In my render function, I would like to use the appropriate style for my components based on the theme.
If the `DarkTheme` is being used on the "mainHeader" class for example, the style of the View component would be something like this:

```
<View style = {DarkTheme.mainHeader}>
</View>
```

If the theme is LightTheme, then it should be:

```
<View style = {LightTheme.mainHeader}>
</View>
```

For efficiency's sake, I thought that if I put the name of the theme in a state variable, I could do something like this:

```
<View style = {{this.state.theme + '.mainHeader'}}>
</View>
```

Expecting the evaluation of the theme variable to return either ***LightTheme.mainHeader*** or ***DarkTheme.mainHeader.***

But I am wrong, this does not work.
Is there anyway I can make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a ternary operator inside of the `render()` to set classes based on the theme that you would reference with `this.state.theme`.

`const classes = this.state.theme === 'dark' ? style.dark : style.light;`

Then in your element you would use it like such with `className`:

`<View className={classes}>`

Here's a quick jsfiddle example. Change the state option from light to dark and the background will change: https://jsfiddle.net/3516s2vg/

Edit: Ok so if you are wanting to use more then one theme here, one option could be to use a switch statement to specify the specific class. I'm not a react expert so I'm not even sure if this would be the best way to go about this. The switch would also go inside of the `render()`.

```
let classes = '';

switch(this.state.theme) {
  case 'dark':
    classes = style.dark;
    break;
  case 'light':
    classes = style.light;
    break;
  case 'other':
    classes = style.other;
    break;
  default:
    classes = style.dark;
}
```

And again to use it you would do `<View className={classes}>`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am currently doing. It works fine with 2 themes but when you try more than 2, the ternary operator quickly becomes ugly.

Comment: Ah yeah if you have more than 2 options I can see that. Let me think for a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You could either:

1. put the actual theme object on state or
2. write a statement in the style attribute that evaluates the string on state.theme and returns the actual object. (haven't tried this one but I believe it would work)

But yeah you can't compose an object name like that with concatenation, or at least not easily.

Here's a great answer about inline styles in React: [React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices) (1st answer from @chantastic)

Worth mentioning, I did something like this on my portfolio page which uses theme provider and styled components, and you can see the code for that functionality here: https://github.com/xezian/xezian/blob/master/client/src/components/Page/Page.js

Comment: I tried number 1 and preferred not go that route.
Number 2 is a good suggestion. I used a ternary operator and that works fine for 2 themes and becomes painful for more than that.

I'll take a look at the links you sent.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing name of the theme in state, try storing the style value.

```
this.state = {
   theme: DarkTheme.mainHeader 
}
```

And directly use the state value

```
<View style = {this.state.theme}>
</View>
```

Comment: Yes, I contemplating doing this but I would have to create so many state variables for each component and I am trying to not overload state because it takes time to render all these components.