# Adding style attribute in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, have this:

```
return (
   <tag>
     { variable ? 
            <p> hello </p>
        :
            <p> world </p>
     }
   </tag>
)
```

As you can see, I am doing a ternary operator to output content depending on `variable`. I want to add `style` attribute in the p tag, like this:

```
<p style="color:#DF0101;font-weight:bold;"> hello </p>
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried:

```
<p style={{color:"#DF0101", font-weight:"bold"}}>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be <p style={{color:"#DF0101", fontWeight:"bold"}}>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `font-weight` but `fontWeight`, you need to use **camelCase** notation

```
 <p style={{color:"#DF0101", fontWeight:"bold"}}>
```

[Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

> The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with **camelCased** properties rather than a CSS string.

---

### Update based on comments

There is a logic error in your example code. The css are not updated, only the text. So use the ternary to change the text.

```
 <p style={{ color:"#DF0101", fontWeight:"bold" }}> 
   {{ lockPost === true ? 'Not ready' : 'Ready!' }} 
 </p>
```

Comment: Still did not work, here is my [exact code](https://pastebin.com/jR2qmbH6). Am I missing something?

Comment: His code is completely fine. See [here](https://repl.it/@Kozandmo/CriticalZigzagEquipment)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have dashes in a JS variable (or key, in this case). You want to use your second example, but replace all dashes with camelCase, like this:

```
<p style={{ color:"#DF0101", fontWeight:"bold" }}>
```

Comment: Still did not work, here is my [exact code](https://pastebin.com/jR2qmbH6). Am I missing something?

Comment: This code works for me. Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Check this [repl.it](https://repl.it/@Kozandmo/CriticalZigzagEquipment) @HenrikPetterson

Answer (score 0):

If you try this, it will work:

```
<p style={{color:"#DF0101", fontWeight:"bold"}}>
```

You should write it with **camelCase**.

font-weight => font**W**eight