# how to assign value in style attribute in html tags in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

This work in simple html css but how to use style and give --i value in react

```
<span style="--i:3;" className="this">
          p
        </span>
```

CSS this is how i used this --i in css

```
 span {
      animation: animate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
      animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
    }
    @keyframes animate {
      0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      20% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
      }
      40%,
      100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding style attribute in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632250/adding-style-attribute-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react, for your HTML, use this syntax :

```
<span style={{ '--i': 3 }} className="this">
     p
</span>
```

Comment: I visited late but thanks :)