# Stacking multiple Transformations of the same Type in Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I want some transformations which are all targeting the same property to stack on top of each other.

Given my example below: If the button is clicked multiple times, the effects should add up. The box should then also move faster to the right according to the frequency of the clicks.

```js
const clickHandler = () => {box.classList.add("move-box");}
```

```css
.box{
width: 50px;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.move-box {
margin-left: 100px;
transition: margin-left 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickHandler()">Go over there</button>
<div id="box" class="box">Alright</div>
```

Comment: simply set `margin-left`

Comment: but thats what I did, right?

Comment: you set it to `100px`, nothing increase it.

Comment: yes :) how would I increase it?

Comment: I've pose an answer. you can directly set style in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set css value dynamically by javascript

(note: you should put `transition: margin-left 0.5s linear;` in `.box`)

```js
const clickHandler = () => {
  const left = +box.dataset.left
  box.style.marginLeft = left + "px";
  box.dataset.left = left + 100;
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickHandler()">Go over there</button>
<div id="box" class="box" data-left=100>Alright</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. Definitely learned something new. Ill try it out

Comment: thats not a solutions which is also working for frameworks, is it? I am working with react and I was hoping that the general solution to the problem might also apply

Comment: @Tobi This is pure js which should always work, if any framework break it, it's their problem to fix it (I believe react allow you to set attribute like [this random search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices) ).

Comment: @Tobi note that react is doing more or less what I'm showing, thus it would conflict with my code (and many native methods).

Comment: I got it working simply using `style = { ... }` as well as moving the transition to the general class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can pass a parameter in your function for the speed and use it in your css instead of using a static value or maybe increment it with every click.

Comment: how could I pass a value to my css stylesheet? That has been an issue as well. I could use inline styles but it think it could be stacked then

Comment: you can use css variables for that .
please refer  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties