# related to React js (props) css inline style

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-css-modules

I want to more than one cards in different background color what i do ?
eg:

```
import React from "react";
import reactDom from "react-dom";

const BgColor=(props)=>{
    
    return(
       <>
        <div className="main_div">
            <div className="cards" >
                <div className="card-side front" >
                    <div><span>C</span>opy<span>C</span>ode</div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-side back">
                    <div><i className="fas fa-copy fs-3" /><br />{props.code}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       </>
    )
}
export default BgColor;
```

by pass value in app.js

and so on.....

please help me how to pass value inside the app.js

Comment: please be more specific. create a codesandbox to help us understand you better

Comment: you want to pass some color to this component from  it's parent?

Answer (score 0):

with this example is hard to to help you. Indeed, we don't know what your props object contains.

Let's assume your props contains

```
{
   name: "toto",
   code: "myCode"
}
```

In order to change background color based on props, you have multiples choices.

You can use dynamics classNames based on your props:

```
const BgColor=(props)=>{
    
    return(
       <>
        <div className="main_div">
            <div className="cards" >
                <div className={`${props.name} card-side front`} >
                    <div><span>C</span>opy<span>C</span>ode</div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-side back">
                    <div><i className="fas fa-copy fs-3" /><br />{props.code}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       </>
    )
}
```

See the *<div className={`${props.name} card-side front`} >* line. Go to css or scss file for this component and add a class selector inside of it.
In our example, it will be

```
.toto {
   background: red
}
```

The second option is to inject directly the css inside your div.

Let's assume you send the desired background color inside your propos:

```
{
   backgroundColor: "red",
   code: "myCode"
}
```

In order to that, you have to do this

```
const BgColor=(props)=>{
        
        return(
           <>
            <div className="main_div">
                <div className="cards" >
                    <div className="card-side front" style={{backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor}}>
                        <div><span>C</span>opy<span>C</span>ode</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-side back">
                        <div><i className="fas fa-copy fs-3" /><br />{props.code}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           </>
        )
    }
```

If you want to know more about css in React, you can check:
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html, [React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices), https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/

**UPDATE**

You can send an array of colors like `<BgColor colors={["red", "blue"]} />` then in your BgColor component, you can map on your props like:

```
    const BgColor=({colors})=>{

     return (
      <div className="main_div">
        <div className="cards">
            {colors.map((color, index) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        className="card-side front"
                        style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
                        key={index}
                    >
                        <div>
                            <span>C</span>opy<span>C</span>ode
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
         </div>
       </div>
     );    
    }
```

Comment: how to pass value for more cards in App.js

Comment: like <BgColor="red" />

Comment: import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import BgColor from "./components/BgColor";



function App() {
  return (
    <div>
       
        <span><BgColor  code="#0093E9"  color=""/></span>
        <span><BgColor  code="#6610f2" color=""/></span>
        <span><BgColor  code="#0093E9" color=""/></span>
    
       </div>       
      
  );
}

export default App;