# Add Css inside react code is not reflecting in website

Tags: reactjs

We are displaying a Wishlist button in website. Now i need to add css  ( color : red ) to that button. so i tried below code :

```
{
  isMobile && (
    <div className={classes.cartActionButton}>
      <div className="px-3 h-[46px] m-auto w-full" style="color:red;">
        {cartActionContent}
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Here is [Website url](https://frontend1.staging.glowjewels.com/dreamy-wonder-diamond-necklace)

but it is not reflecting in the website. Is that a correct way to add css in react code ?

I want to change color of wishlist button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js inline style best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882177/react-js-inline-style-best-practices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `style` prop in React.js accepts Object not string

```js
{
  isMobile && (
    <div className={classes.cartActionButton}>
      <div className="px-3 h-[46px] m-auto w-full" style={{ color: "red" }}>
        {cartActionContent}
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: will the `style={{ color: "red" }}` apply for `<Suspense fallback={null}>
          <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} />
        </Suspense>` ?

Comment: or is there any way to apply css for  `<Suspense fallback={null}>
          <WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} />
        </Suspense>`

Comment: will apply for the `div` defined in. `<Suspense>` isn't stylable. To style the `<WishlistButton />` pass the style prop to it

Comment: `<WishlistButton {...wishlistButtonProps} style={{ color: "red" }} />`. Where WishlistButton come from?